# Prolog: count only direct child nodes of a parent using pure recursion

Tags: tree, prolog, parent, children

Is it possible in **Prolog** to count number of direct child nodes of a parent using recursion without `retract` / `aggregate` etc?

For example, say we have the following:

```
parent(p1, child_node1).
parent(p1, child_node2).
parent(p1, child_node3).
parent(p1, child_node4).

parent(child_node1, another_node1).
parent(child_node1, another_node2).
parent(child_node2, another_node3).
parent(child_node2, another_node4).
parent(child_node3, another_node5).
parent(child_node3, another_node6).
parent(child_node4, another_node7).
parent(child_node4, another_node8).
```

How do we count using recursion that **p1** has **4** direct child nodes?

Comment: Why not with `findall/3`? Using recursion will make the program inefficient, since it basically will each time make another walk over the evaluation tree.

Comment: I am just interested whether (and how) it could be achieved using only pure recursion, so to say. Of course, there are more effective ways to achieve this.

Comment: did you come up with a sketch (or attempt) to solve this yourself?

Comment: I am able to achieve this using one of `retract` / `aggregate_all` or `findall/3`, but without them I have not had much success. My current thoughts are to create a list and populate it with children then count its length. However, being sort of new to Prolog I feel like I am missing something, unsure how do I go about making sure I don't loop forever over the same children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to maintain a list of children we have already seen, and each time querying for a child, that is not yet a member of that list. Each time we find a child, we recurse and we add the child to the list. In case we no longer can find such child, we can just unify the result with the thus far obtained children.

```
count_children(Parent, N) :-
    count_children(Parent, [], 0, N).

count_children(Parent, L, N0, N) :-
    (parent(Parent, C), \+member(C, L))
    -> (N1 is N0+1, count_children(Parent, [C|L], N1, N))
    ; N = N0.
```

For example:

```
?- count_children(p1, N).
N = 4.

?- count_children(child_node1, N).
N = 2.

?- count_children(child_node2, N).
N = 2.

?- count_children(child_node3, N).
N = 2.

?- count_children(child_node4, N).
N = 2.

?- count_children(another_node1, N).
N = 0.
```

If the parent is not unified however, it will unify with the first parent, and stop after it obtained the first result:

```
?- count_children(P, N).
P = p1,
N = 4.
```

I leave it as an exercise to let this unify with all possible parents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, it cleared up the thing for me.